# Typescript compile error in Redux Toolkit createAsyncThunk.ts

Tags: node.js, typescript, redux-toolkit

I am having trouble with Typescript and Redux Toolkit. My code seems to be ok, but I am getting this error:

```
/home/mp/JsProjects/myproject/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/src/createAsyncThunk.ts
TypeScript error in /home/mp/JsProjects/myproject/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/src/createAsyncThunk.ts(508,11):
Property 'abort' is missing in type '{ aborted: false; addEventListener(): void; dispatchEvent(): false; onabort(this: AbortSignal): void; removeEventListener(): void; }' but required in type 'AbortSignal'.  TS2741

    506 |       ? AbortController
    507 |       : class implements AbortController {
  > 508 |           signal: AbortSignal = {
        |           ^
    509 |             aborted: false,
    510 |             addEventListener() {},
    511 |             dispatchEvent() {
```

I'm using:

- @redux-toolkit v1.6.1
- node v16.4.1

I realize this is a typing file from the npm module. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: After removing some unused imports, the problem disappeared. I'm not sure how, but at least my issue was solved.